# Why is the autocompletion feature (used to create a title on SO) not used in the Search Q&A Field?

Tags: discussion, search, top-bar

I think the autocompletion feature should be added to the Search Q&A field (text field in the upper right corner of this website). This feature may help reduce the number of duplicate questions asked on this website. I am curious as to why it wasn't used in this particular location. Thoughts?

Comment: I think this and other things may be implemented by SO.  There was a big Q just recently about penalizing people who answer blatant dupes and one of the big takeaways was we need to make finding dupes easier.  This hopefully would be one of the features that is implemented to accomplish that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want from "auto-complete"?  It is just a search box.  Do you want it to behave more like the chrome address bar and guess what you are trying to search from what you have typed so far?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yup. I was about to post a question on SO after searching a few times using Search Q&A with no luck. However, while I was writing out the title to my question, the duplicate question magically appeared. Had it appeared in the Search Q&A field, I would have saved a good 30 minutes of searching :).

Comment: Given that the search isn't that great to begin with, I wouldn't expect to get useful autocompletions.